# How to validate identity document numbers (passport, id card)?

Tags: php, validation, identity, documents

I have to validate some ID numbers, focusing on italian and spanish ID. For example, identity card (carta d'identità), passport, driving licence (patente) etc.
I tried to search all over the web to get the validation rules (how many chars does compose an idnumber? how they are computed?) but I really cannot find a regexp or some rules that can help me.
I have to validate these numbers when registering a user because I would like to know if his document is valid or not, via validation (email addresses have a specific format....does this format exists for the submentioned identity documents?)
Do anyone knows:
1) Where to get the validation rules (e.g. number of chars, two digits and seven characters....)
2) if exists some php library which does the job?
Currently, I can validate only the fiscal code (codice fiscale) and the spanish DNI, which have some predefined rules to be calculated.
Thanks in advance,
Gioia

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: My bad, I've integrated the question as you suggested.

Comment: Please add some code as well f you have searched for it as well, for number of chars use `maxlength in input type field`

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for. I know how to do the validation. I'm asking for the rules of validation. In italy, how is made up a passport number? and a carta d'identità? and a driving licence? In spain, how is made up a passport number?

Comment: I read it before posting the question. It doesn't seems to answer my question. I'd like to know if anyone has encountered this problem and has a solution or if exists a library that does the job. I already know that passport validation rules differs from country to country. I asked if anyone knows the exact format of italian and spanish passport, the format of the carta d'identità and the format of the driving licence.